# Updating struct members in a for-loop

Tags: c, gcc, struct

Is there a way to update struct members in a for loop, I want to avoid having to update the members one-by-one. For example:

Instead of doing this:

```
void Update(int vaule,struct Coolstruct *Ice)
{
    int vaule;
    Ice->member1=vaule;
    Ice->member2=vaule;
    Ice->member3=vaule;
    Ice->member4=vaule;
}
```

I was wondering if something similar to this (pseudocode) was possible:

```
void Update(int vaule,struct Coolstruct *Ice)
{
    int vaule;

    for(int i=0;i++;i<4)
    {
        Ice->i =vaule
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what arrays are for.

Comment: you can modify your struct definition to replace the separated *member<i>* by an array memorizing all of them, but the initialization must not be the alone reason to modify it, that must make sense to do. Warning, in *Update* you mask the parameter *vaule* by a variable having the same name and not initialized, the behavior is undefined

Comment: `struct Coolstruct { int member[4]; };`

Comment: This `for(int i=0;i++;i<4)` does not what you expect.

Comment: (a) Do not do this. Stop trying. The reason C does not have a proper tool for this is that it is not needed, and there is a better way to accomplish your actual goal. (b) If you want to access members as an array, they should be defined as an array. it is easier to access elements of an array individually (such as `Ice->member[3]`) than to access struct members as an array. (c) A proper (strictly conforming C) solution can be implemented using `offsetof` and an auxiliary array that provides a map of the members within the structure. Do not do this; it is a waste.

Comment: (d) There are various kludges, relying on implementation-defined behavior, that can be used to do this. Do not do this; it is unnecessary and is bad form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

But you need an array of objects inside of the structure `Coolstruct` instead of defining multiple single objects.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Coolstruct {
   int b[4];
};

void Update(int vaule, struct Coolstruct *Ice)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        Ice->b[i] = vaule;
    }

    return;
}

int main(void) {

   struct Coolstruct x;

   int y = 25;

   Update(y, &x);   

   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
       printf("x.b[%d] = %d\n", i, x.b[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
x.b[0] = 25
x.b[1] = 25
x.b[2] = 25
x.b[3] = 25
```